# How can I create and push to a shared or distributed array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, julia

I have written Julia code in which I initialize an empty array as follows:

a = []

Later in the code, I simply push to this array as follows:

push![a, b]

where b = [c, d, e, ...] is another array, and each b can be of different length.

This works just fine in un-parallelized code. However, I want to do the same thing in parallelized code where a = [] is a shared or distributed array that the different processors can push to.

Neither SharedArray or DArray worked for me. Any advice?

Comment: Remember to always [tag your question with the language you are using](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) -- [tag:julia] in this case. The language tag is the most important tag to use when asking questions; without it, the question is more difficult to find (for those answering & for future viewers).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you should always need to declare what are you holding in your array `[]` means `Any[]` and it is almost never a good idea.

Let us consider this vector with placeholders:

```
julia> a=[Int[] for _ in 1:8]
8-element Vector{Vector{Int64}}:
 []
 []
 []
 []
 []
 []
 []
 []
```

This `Vector` contains 8 references to other `Vector`s.

Let us now distribute it:

```
julia> using Distributed; addprocs(4);

julia> @everywhere using DistributedArrays

julia> b = distribute(a)
8-element DArray{Vector{Int64}, 1, Vector{Vector{Int64}}}:
 []
 []
 []
 []
 []
 []
 []
 []
```

This new `b` is now available through all worker processes where each worker holds its `localpart` of it. Let us mutate it!

```
julia> fetch(@spawnat 2 append!(localpart(b)[1], [1,2,3,4]));

julia> fetch(@spawnat 3 append!(localpart(b)[2], [10,20]));

julia> fetch(@spawnat 3 push!(localpart(b)[2], 30))
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 10
 20
 30
```

We can see that everything is working as expected (we have used `fetch` to make sure our code actually got executed on remote workers).

Let us know check on the master process the state of `b`:

```
julia> b
8-element DArray{Vector{Int64}, 1, Vector{Vector{Int64}}}:
 [1, 2, 3, 4]
 []
 []
 [10, 20, 30]
 []
 []
 []
 []
```

You can see that we have successfully used remote workers to mutate `b`.

Answer (score 0):

I asked a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71774923/create-sparse-matrix-in-parallel-in-julia). I originally followed Prezmyslaw's answer but could not get `distribute` to distribute an already existing array the way I thought it would for Julia 1.7. What worked for me was defining the array as it was initialized :

```
using Distributed
addprocs(4)
@everywhere using DistributedArrays

a = distribute([[] for _ in procs()])

@sync @distributed for i = 1:10
  b = fill(i, 5)
  append!(localpart(a)[1], b)  # I swapped push! for append!
end

a
```

What this does is: first it creates an array with subarrays that are distributed to each worker, then it distributes computation and fills the corresponding subarrays with the values calculated on each worker, finally it merges the subarrays to obtain a full array with all the values.

It is interesting to compare this with the exact same code but substituting `a = distribute([[] for _ in procs()])` for `a = [[] for _ in procs()]; distribute(a)`. Evidently the latter does not work as expected (at least for Julia 1.7).