# Create sparse matrix in parallel in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, sparse-matrix, distributed-computing

I am trying to parallelize the creation of a sparse matrix in Julia. Inspired by this post [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66276664/how-can-i-create-and-push-to-a-shared-or-distributed-array-of-arrays) I am trying this:

```
using Distributed
addprocs(4)
@everywhere using DistributedArrays

rows = [Int[] for _ in procs()]
cols = [Int[] for _ in procs()]
vals = [Float64[] for _ in procs()]
distribute(rows)
distribute(cols)
distribute(vals)

@sync @distributed for i = 1:1000
    for j = 1:1000
        v = exp(-(i - j)^2)
        if v > 0.1
            push!(localpart(rows)[1], i)
            push!(localpart(cols)[1], j)
            push!(localpart(vals)[1], v)
        end
    end
end

ROWS = vcat(rows...)
COLS = vcat(cols...)
VALS = vcat(vals...)

K = sparse(ROWS, COLS, VALS)
# K = 0×0 SparseMatrixCSC{Float64, Int64} with 0 stored entries
```

This outputs an empty matrix, and it does not get filled. But I found that if I call `@fetchfrom 2 rows`, the rows that it creates is not empty. So it seems that it is just not combining everything.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I think you have to work on the result of `distribute`. You can't magically modify a Base `Array` to be distributed.

Comment: @phipsgabler I changed ``rows = [Int[] for _ in procs()]; distribute(rows)`` to ``rows = dfill(Int[], nprocs())`` and now everything works. Thank you! If you put that in an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`distribute(rows)` does not modify `rows` to be distributed; it returns a new distributed array filled with the input.  You have to work with its result, something like

```
rows = distribute([Int[] for _ in procs()])
```