# Synchronously Outputting to DistributedArray of Vectors in Parallel

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I'm trying to distribute a function that outputs a vector into an array.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66276664/how-can-i-create-and-push-to-a-shared-or-distributed-array-of-arrays) post with something like the following code:

```
a = distribute([Float64[] for _ in 1:nrow(df)])
@sync @distributed for i in 1:nrow(df)
  append!(localpart(a)[i], foo(df[i]))
end
```

But I get the following error:

> BoundsError: attempt to access 145-element Vector{Vector{Float64}} at index [147]

I've only ever parallelized with SharedArrays, which aren't an option, since I need to store vectors in the shared array. Any and all advice would be life-saving.

Answer (score 1):

Each localpart is indexed starting from one.
Hence you need to convert between a global index and the local index.

The function `DistributedArrays.localindices()` returns a one element tuple that contains a range of global indices that are mapped to the localpart.
This information can be in turn used for the index conversion:

```
@sync @distributed for i in 1:nrow(df)
    id = i - DistributedArrays.localindices(a)[1][1] + 1
    push!(localpart(a)[id], f(df[i,1]))
end
```

#### EDIT

to understand how `localindiced` work look at this code:

```
julia> addprocs(4);

julia>  a = distribute([Float64[] for _ in 1:14]);

julia> fetch(@spawnat 2 DistributedArrays.localindices(a))
(1:4,)

julia> fetch(@spawnat 3 DistributedArrays.localindices(a))
(5:8,)

julia> fetch(@spawnat 4 DistributedArrays.localindices(a))
(9:11,)

julia> fetch(@spawnat 5 DistributedArrays.localindices(a))
(12:14,)
```

Comment: Thank you for this response! On the id definition line, I get "syntax: incomplete: premature end of output".

Comment: Edit: it looks like DistributedArrays.localindices(1)[1] is a UnitRange type with the value 1:0. I'm not sure what to make of that.

Comment: OK, I figured out how to make this work: collect(DistributedArrays.localindices(a)[1])[1] does the trick, and my code is running and spitting out the desired output. Thank you!

Comment: It is `DistributedArrays.localindices(a)[1][1]`, not `DistributedArrays.localindices(1)[1]`. The result will depend on the value of `myid()` each worker will get a different range because it holds a different part of array. You do not need the `collect`